# Laravel 5.5 Project Download File Insted Of Opening Them In Browser PHP 7.1 MAC

Tags: laravel, macos, laravel-5, xampp, php-7.1

I am developing laravel 5.5 project PHP 7.1.32 on windows it works fine. Now I Shifted To Mac OSX I copied the whole project from windows to mac instead of opening the file in browser it downloads the file (download). When i hit public folder into address bar. The Downloaded File Content Is as Follow

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: `windows it works fine` what error are you facing in mac?

Comment: It didnt opening file when i hit url localhost/project-name/public . Instead of opening it it download the file

Comment: @DilipHirapara Just Updated Question So It will be more explainable

Answer (score 0):

You can't just hit the public folder and expect to run your app by php. Firstly should serve the app.

You can use phps builtin webserver with `php artisan serve` on app base directory, or you can use a web server like apache or nginx.

If you already serving your app, then there is misconfiguration on your server config and you should give more info..

I suggest homestead btw.

Comment: I know PHP artisan serve run my project and its on localhost:8000 but all my URL are localhost/project/public instead of localhost:8000/login